# Two nodes consensus network and its phase plot

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, graph-theory

This is my first day to learn these stuff. I am confused about the following:

Suppose the underlying graph is just two nodes with edge value $1$.

So the adjacency matrix is:  $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

with the degree matrix $$D =\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

So the graph Laplacian: $L = D - A$. The consensus protocol should be $$\dot{x} = -Lx = \begin{bmatrix} x_2-x_1  \\ x_1-x_2 \end{bmatrix}$$

So let $x_0 = [0.25;-0.25]$, we have the following plot:

[image]

However, the phase plot is the following. Does this phase plot imply any consensus information? I cannot understand "consensus" from the following phase plot. What I mean is $x=0.25$ won't go to $0$ which contradicts the above plot. Please advise, thanks!

[image]

Comment: Can you write the DEs describing the consensus protocol dynamics?

Comment: @Dmitry Dynamics is in my article, which is just a linear case.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, overlooked that. Your phase plot must be just a straight line from (0.25, -0.25) to (0,0) as (0.25,-0.25) is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue -2. There seems to be something wrong with your phase plot plotter. The phase plot even does not pass through (0.25,-0.25)

Answer (score 0):

Your phase plot is correct. The states may not converge to zero since the Laplacian matrix has exactly 0 (zero) eigenvalue. According to your initial conditions, the states converge to the line $x=y$. Besides, consensus means that all states converge to the same value. It doesn't have to be zero.